# Limiting shell access for git users, but still allowing push / pull access

Tags: ssh, permissions, shell, git, github

I'm host a git repository on my server. Anyone can `push` / `pull` from the following remote url:

```
ssh://git@example.com/opt/git/my-project.git
```

Specifically, anyone with `ssh` access to the `git@example.com` user can push/pull (i.e. I have their public key listed as an `authorized_key`)

I'd like continue allowing push/pull access but I'd like to *disable shell/login access*

Github uses this approach - if you try to ssh into any of their git servers you get:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi [USER]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Specifically, I'd like to -

1. Disable shell access via ssh and password for the `git` user
2. Still allow myself (as `root`) to be able to assume the `git` user interactively
3. Still allow developers to `push` / `pull` on the repository

I tried disabling the shell for the `git` user as follows:

```
root@example:~# usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin git
```

This works great for #1 (`ssh` access is blocked) and #2 (I can still access the shell with `sudo -u git -s /bin/bash`)

However, #3 is not do-able. Cutting off shell access apparently also disables `push`/`pull` access (since it probably uses `ssh`).

Is there another solution here? How does Github themselves do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use git-shell as the user's login-shell.

A detailed description on how to set this up can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell or alternatively on the git shell manpage `man git shell`

Answer (score 0):

In the authorized_keys file you can add options/restrictions to what is allowed when authenticating with a particular key pair.

Add the restrictions: `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`

See authorized_keys file format description in https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8) for their meaning

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCB... comment 

no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDE... other comment
```

You can add similar restrictions to the git account by setting them in a "match user" block in the sshd_config file:

```
### add this to the bottom of the sshd_config
Match User git
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
```